# Difference between two series of real numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

If I am having two series of real numbers say $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ 
 and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$, when does it makes sense to write $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$-$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$=$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n-b_n)$. Is the only case when it makes sense to write is when both series are convergent? Any other cases when I can write so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_n$; $R_n=\sum_{i=1}^n b_n$;

$T_n:=S_n-R_n$;

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} T_n =\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(S_n-R_n)=$

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}S_n -\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}R_n,$ if the individual limits exist.

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense for *any* two series of real numbers, if you are talking about the series themselves. But if you are talking about their sums, then that expression only makes sense if both series are convergent.

Unfortunately, the notation $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ is ambiguous, since it means both the series itself as its sum (when it exists).